# Reindexing failing on Category Products

Tags: error, reindex

I'm attempting to reindex my Category Products but i keep getting the following error. I'm can't make heads nor tails of it, any one have any ideas?

> Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`magento`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON
>   DEL)

Comment: Does this post solve it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594063/magento-and-error-1452-integrity-constraint-violation-on-reindex-catalog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion would be to truncate the table `catalog_category_product_index` as this will be recreated on index success. It is maybe not the most ideal solution but would hopefully allow for the index to start working again, hopefully this time without any errors.

Normally I would not suggest truncating tables but you should be fairly safe with the index tables, but of course please **backup your database and ideally try this on a testing environment first.**

Comment: Had to scrap that database in the end. Backing up is golden advice.